# LMFIT - How to get best fit with only positive values

Tags: lmfit

I would like to force the best fit to be always positive.

```
from lmfit.models import ExpressionModel
from lmfit.models import StepModel

step_mod = StepModel(form='linear', prefix='step_')

gmod = ExpressionModel("1-exp_amp*exp(-x/exp_decay)")

mod =  gmod*step_mod
pars = gmod.make_params(exp_amp=1, exp_decay=30)
pars += step_mod.guess(y, x=x, amplitude=1,center=23,sigma=0)

out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)

print(out.fit_report())

plt.plot(x, y,'o')
# plt.plot(x, out.init_fit, '--', label='initial fit')
plt.plot(x, out.best_fit, '-', label='best fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And this is the result: [Always positive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycMrc.png)

```
    [[Model]]
    (Model(_eval) * Model(step, prefix='step_', form='linear'))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 37
    # data points      = 370
    # variables        = 5
    chi-square         = 2.53597470
    reduced chi-square = 0.00694788
    Akaike info crit   = -1833.68223
    Bayesian info crit = -1814.11472
##  Warning: uncertainties could not be estimated:
    step_center:     at initial value
    step_sigma:      at boundary
[[Variables]]
    exp_amp:         1.80889259 (init = 1)
    exp_decay:       40.0313587 (init = 30)
    step_amplitude:  1.02997887 (init = 1)
    step_center:     23.0000000 (init = 23)
    step_sigma:      0.00000000 (init = 0)
```

However, it's still not perfect (for example step_center and step_sigma are the same as the beginnig) and if I manually change the center of the step function, this is what I get [Negative values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH0uI.png)

Is there a way to fit getting only positive values? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put bounds on parameter values so that `step_amplitude` is always positive and `exp_decay` is always positive.   That should ensure that your function is always > 0.  You should investigate why parameters are stuck at the boundaries.  For example, guessing `step_sigma` of 0 is probably unwise.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes clear, we can bound the parameters.  But, in general, would there be a way to act directly on the fit function? Thank you again.

Comment: Well, you can write a model function, and then you can sort of do whatever you want.